# computing ζ function of some simple varieties over finite field

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, zeta-functions, betti-numbers

The weil conjectures can be proved by using some algebraic geometry methods and the establish of etale cohomology.
However, can I compute ζ functions over finte field for some simple examples of varieties directly，without using advanced concepts such as scheme and etale cohomology？
Just for

1. the projective line
2. projective spaces
3. elliptic curves
   Moreover，what's thier corresponding complex varieties which satisfies the betti number argument.

Comment: For 1. 2. it suffices to define and count the points of $V(\mathbf{F}_{p^k})$. For 3. show the Frobenius has a quadratic characteristic polynomial $x^2 + tx + p = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta) = 0$ ([see there](http://www.pdmi.ras.ru/~lowdimma/BSD/Silverman-Arithmetic_of_EC.pdf)) so that $\# E(\mathbf{F}_{p^n}) = p^n+1-\alpha^n -\beta^n$

Comment: The zeta function ζ(X, s) of X is by definition $exp(\sum{\frac{N_m}{m}q^{-ms}})$.In the case $N_m=q^m+1$,how can I get the function is just $1/(1-q^{-s})(1-q^{1-s})$,and the same confuse for other cases.

Comment: I wonder if I can use the expansion formula of ln（1-x）？

Comment: Yes it follows from integrating the geometric series to obtain $-\log(1-x) = \sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{x^m}{m}$ as convergent series for $|x|<1$ and as formal series in general. Also you should prove $\exp(\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{N_m}{m} x^m) = \prod_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(1-p^m)^{M_m}}$ where $M_m =\frac{1}{m} \sum_{d | m} N_{m/d} \mu(d)$. In the case of an affine variety over $\mathbf{F}_q$,  $N_m = \# V(\mathbf{F}_{q^m})$ and $M_m$ is the number of maximal ideals of degree $m$ in $\mathbf{F}[x_1,\ldots,x_N]/I(V)$